# git как посмотреть какие изменения были файле который был изменен но не закомичен и не добавлен через git add

Tags: git

git как посмотреть какие изменения были файле который был изменен но не закомичен и не добавлен через git add ?

Т.е. нужно сравнить файл и этим же файлов из HEAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
git diff path/to/filename
```

Результат выглядит так:

```
- text text text
+ Text Text Text
```

Строка с минусом - файл в HEAD, строка с плюсом - измененный файл.

Comment: спасибо, обнял!

Comment: @sdfsdfsdf Обнимать и целовать не надо. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: еще 5 мин пишет :)